# OpenGL texture showing as a solid object?

Tags: c, opengl, colors, textures, rendering

So I have my textures loading in correctly as far as I know, as different shades of brown are being applied to a table I am making, that uses 2 different textures. However the texture is showing as a solid colour with no detail in it.
I have no idea what is causing this.

This is my code for loading bmp textures:

```
GLuint LoadTexture(const char * filename){
GLuint texture;

int width, height;

unsigned char * data;

FILE * file;

file = fopen(filename, "rb");

if(file == NULL)
    return 0;
width = 512;
height = 1024;
data = (unsigned char *) malloc (width * height * 3);

fread(data, width * height * 3, 1, file);
fclose(file);

for(int i = 0; i < width * height; ++i){
    int index = i * 3;
    unsigned char B,R;
    B = data[index];
    R = data[index + 2];

    data[index] = R;
    data[index + 2] = B;
}

glGenTextures(1, &texture);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
glTexEnvf(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_MODULATE);
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_NEAREST);

glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
gluBuild2DMipmaps(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 3,width, height, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);

return texture;
}

void loadTextures(){
tableTopTexture = LoadTexture("table_top.bmp");
tableLegTexture = LoadTexture("table_leg.bmp");
}
```

And then I use it like so in a drawTable method:

```
void drawTable(){

//texture stuff
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glTexEnvf(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_DECAL);



//draw legs
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tableLegTexture);
glTexCoord2f(0.0,0.0);
drawCube(0.050,0.5,0.060,0,0,0);
glTexCoord2f(0.0,1.0);
drawCube(0.050,0.5,0.060,3,0,0);
glTexCoord2f(1.0,1.0);
drawCube(0.050,0.5,0.060,3,0,-1);
glTexCoord2f(1.0,0.0);
drawCube(0.050,0.5,0.060,0,0,-1);

//draw table top
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tableTopTexture);
glTexCoord2f(0.0,0.0);
glTexCoord2f(1.0,0.0);
glTexCoord2f(1.0,1.0);
glTexCoord2f(0.0,1.0);
drawCube(2,0.050,1,1.5,0.5,-0.5);

glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
}
```

Here is a pastebin of the complete code:: http://pastebin.com/0Ns5JdDX

Comment: That's...not how texture coordinates work.

Comment: @genpfault yeah I am sort of confused as to how they work. how exactly does it work?

Comment: You need a `glTexCoord2f()` before each `glVertex3f()`.

Comment: How should I approach it with the way I am doing it? I have the drawCube which is how I create all the objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a `glTexCoord2f()` before each `glVertex3f()`.

Otherwise multiple vertices will have the same texcoord, resulting in sampling a single color from your texture.

Comment: Yeah I was thinking I was doing the TexCoords wrong. Can I have 6 texCoord calls before each drawCube? Or does it have to be in drawCube? I create each object using drawCube so I'm not sure how to best go about it. I mean, could I just specify all the glTexCoord2fs in the drawCube, and pass drawCube the texture I want it to use?

Comment: @AndyOHart: think of glTexCoord and glVertex something like this: `glTexCoord(tc) { tc_state = tc;}` and `glVertex(vp) { send_vertex_to_GPU(vp, tc_state);}` – I think you figure what that means. Honestly you shouldn't use immediate mode (glBegin, glVertex) at all. Use vertex array; Had you used VAs in the first place you'd not even have tripped into that pitfall.